# Район следует курсу [по курсу?], взятому Главой республики

Tags: грамотная-речь, управление

Как правильно: *следует **по курсу*** или *следует **курсу***?
**Район следует курсу, взятому Главой республики.**

Comment: Вот курсу или по курсу – не знаю, но глава республики – точно со строчной.

Answer (score 1):

**Курс** - многозначное слово. Нам пригодятся 2:

1) направление движения;
2) перен. направление какой-либо деятельности.

*Район следует* (= идёт, развивается, продвигается вперёд) как? *курсом, взятым Главой республики.*

***Пример из Нацкорпуса (один из двух)***: *По мнению экспертов, Арсенис оставит кабинет почти без изменений и в основном будет **следовать курсом** Папандреу.* [Валерия Сычева. Выборы нового премьера Греции (1996) // «Коммерсантъ-Daily», 1996.01.19]

*Район следует (чему?) курсу, взятому Главой республики.*

***Пример из Нацкорпуса (единственный)***: *Поддерживаем эти усилия ДОИ и призываем не снижать темпов, твердо **следовать курсу** на формирование культуры коммуникации как одного из ключевых элементов реформирования и повышения эффективности всей системы ООН.* [Б. Н. Малахов. Выступление на 26-й сессии Комитета ООН по информации (2004) // «Дипломатический вестник», 2004.05.25]

Answer (score 1):

Правильно: **Район следует курсу, взятому главой республики.**

Из словаря:

СЛЕДОВАТЬ 4. (св. последовать). **кому-чему.** Руководствоваться чем-л.; поступать согласно чему-л. или подобно кому-л. Во всём с. старшему брату. С. советам врача. С. чьему-л. примеру. С. каким-л. правилам. С. обычаям предков. С. моде. С. духу времени. С. своему желанию. С. поставленной цели. 5. Двигаться, перемещаться куда-л., откуда-л. Поезд следует со всеми остановками. Экспедиция следует на восток. Машины следуют в одном направлении.

Но **в прямом значении слова (двигаться. перемещаться)**: *корабль следовал по курсу (курсом).*

Пример: *Чебоксары следуют курсу, взятому главой Чувашской Республики*

https://regnum.ru/news/2172064.html

Answer (score 0):

В словарях управления ([на Академике](https://upravlenie.academic.ru/2190) и [на Грамоте](http://gramota.ru/slovari/dic/?word=%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C&all=x)):
**следовать**
(поступать подобно кому-либо; руководствоваться чьим-либо примером) **кому-чему** и **за кем-чем**.
Во всём следуйте этим людям (за этими людьми). Следовать советам врача.
*Следуйте всегда внушениям вашего сердца...* (Т.)
*Да, смешные это люди, как Рахметов... Не следуйте за ними...* (Черн.)
Лучше следовать за рекомендациями специалиста.

Правильно:
**Район следует курсу, взятому главой республики.**
[[Глава](https://dic.academic.ru/dic.nsf/es/15934) — тот, кто возглавляет что-либо, руководит чем-либо. **Избрать главу района.**]

Следовать политическому курсу партии.
*Эстонское государство не должно слепо следовать курсу Запада* (BaltNews.ee).

Answer (score 0):

По поводу словаря управления.
Да, какая-то недоработка в этом словаре. Выражения типа *следовать путём, следовать дорогой, следовать курсом* и т.п. повсеместно распространены и в других словарях упоминаются (например, в "Словаре глагольно-именных словосочетаний" Дерягиной).

В данном случае допустимы два варианта: **следовать курсу** и **следовать курсом**.

Answer (score 0):

Мне кажется, оба варианта возможны, но есть смысловая разница.
*Следовать курсом* (обычно *указанным кем-то*, *проложенным кем-то*) — двигаться в указанном направлении. Применительно к району звучит чрезмерно возвышенно. (Район идет вслед за главой Чувашской Республики). *Следовать курсу* — здесь "курс" скорее воспринимается как набор идей, которым нужно следовать.

А с другой стороны, в этой фразе глава республики не *разработал*, не *предложил* курс, а  **взял курс**, что возвращает нас к советской риторике (Следуя курсом, определенным XXV съездом КПСС, октябрьским (1976 г. [Смирнов Игорь. Адреса комсомольской пятилетки // «Техника - молодежи», 1977]) и делает уместным следование строго за главой республики: **Район следует курсом, взятым главой Чувашской Республики.**